# Sort TableView with Entity

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, xcode5

This works but it's getting sorted randomly every time.

In points there is point.pointOrder which is a NSNumber. I would like to sort them after point.pointOrder. Can anyone point ;) me in the right direction please?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    OIOISingleTourTableViewCell *cell = (OIOISingleTourTableViewCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    point = [[self.tour.tour_infopoint allObjects] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lblInfoPointName.text = point.pointName;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad i did this:

```
pointArray = [self.tour.tour_infopoint allObjects];

NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"pointOrder" ascending:YES];
sortedPointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[pointArray copy]];
[sortedPointArray sort UsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];
```

and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
point = [sortedPointArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 2):

A `NSSet` is never sorted. You need to sort it using `NSSortDescriptor`

```
NSArray *infoPointArray = [self.tour.tour_infopoint sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pointOrder" ascending:YES]];
```

Then use the `infoPointArray` instead of `[self.tour.tour_infopoint allObjects]`

Comment: Just after I published the question I solved it. Similar to ur answer. Thx.

Comment: @hugocarlmartin - Consider providing your answer to your own question or perhaps accepting this one if it's very similar.